# std::unordered_map::operator[] - why there are two signatures?

Tags: c++, c++11, unordered-map, rvalue-reference

In the C++11, there are two versions of **std::unordered_map::operator[]**, namely:

```
mapped_type& operator[] ( const key_type& k ); //1
mapped_type& operator[] ( key_type&& k ); //2
```

There are two questions:

1) Why the second one is necessary - the first one allows to pass constant to the function, since the first one contains the keyword **const**

2) For example, which version, 1 or 2, will be called in this case:

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, int> testmap;
testmap["test"] = 1;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Normally, the key is only used for comparison purposes, so you might wonder why rvalue semantics are necessary: a const reference should already cover that case.

But one thing to note is that operator[] can indeed create a new key/value pair: if the key wasn't already existent in the map.

In that case, if the second overload was used, then the map can safely move the provided key value in the map (while default initializing the value). It's a pretty rare and negligible optimization in my opinion, but when you're the C++ standard library, you shouldn't spare any efforts to save someone a cycle, even if it happens just once!

As for the second question, I might be wrong but it should consider the second overload as the best overload.

Edit:
There is also a valid point that it might allow you to use move-only objects as key values, even if it's a debatable decision

Comment: I am not sure it is done for optimization, you probably missing that some types are movable but not copy-able. In that case you would not be able to use such type as a key without this overload.

Comment: @Slava That's a pretty valid point, I'll even include it in my answer, but I fail to see in practice why you would want a move-only type as a key type for a map.
You wouldn't have a mutex, a thread or a unique pointer as a key. You should only use types that behave like value types

Answer (score 1):

It's there for performance reasons. For example if the key is an rvalue, the key is moved instead of copied when a new element is inserted.

Thus, you avoid extra copy of an object/key. You can see this in the following example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>

struct Foo {
  Foo() { std::cout << "Foo() called" << std::endl; }
  Foo(Foo const &other) { std::cout << "Foo(Foo const &other) called" << std::endl; }
  Foo(Foo &&other) { std::cout << "Foo(Foo &&other) called" << std::endl; }
  int i = 0;
};

bool operator==(Foo const &lhs, Foo const &rhs) {
  return lhs.i == rhs.i;
}

void hash_combine(std::size_t& seed, const Foo& v) {
    std::hash<int> hasher;
    seed ^= hasher(v.i) + 0x9e3779b9 + (seed<<6) + (seed>>2);
}

struct CustomHash {
  std::size_t operator()(Foo const& v) const  {
    std::size_t res = 0;
    hash_combine(res, v);
    return res;
  }
};

int main() {
  std::unordered_map<Foo, int, CustomHash> fmap;

  Foo a;
  a.i = 100;
  fmap[a] = 100;
  fmap[Foo()] = 1;

}
```

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6b1105a1d53516dc)

### Output:

```
Foo() called
Foo(Foo const &other) called
Foo() called
Foo(Foo &&other) called
```

As can see in the case `fmap[Foo()] = 1;` the rvalue object is moved in contrast with statement `fmap[a] = 100;` where a copy constructor is called.